# Absolute value of complex exponential $e^{1-i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How does $|e^{1-i}|=e$ ?

I know it has something to do with Euler's formula, but I don't see it. The other thread I found didn't make much sense to me. This is how far I got:

$e^{1-i}=e^1(\cos ({-1})+i\sin ({-1}))=e(\cos ({1})-i\sin ({1}))$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|e^{1-i}|=|e^1(\cos ({-1})+i\sin ({-1}))|=|e(\cos ({1})-i\sin ({1}))|=e\sqrt{\cos^2 1+\sin^2 1}=e$

Comment: Thanks. How would you go about the argument of the same number?

Comment: argument is $\arctan(-\sin 1/\cos 1)=\arctan(-\tan 1)=\arctan(\tan(-1))=-1$

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of the complex modulus $$\left|z\right| := \sqrt{z\bar{z}}$$ We get $$\left|e^{1-i}\right| = \left|ee^{-i}\right| = e\left|e^{-i}\right| = e\sqrt{e^{-i}e^{i}} = e\sqrt{e^0} = e$$

Comment: You have written $e=1.$